# Pass / echo DIV ID (letter) into input value based on another input value (Number between 0-100)

Tags: php, input

I have form that I created that is sending specific data to a database to be retrieved on another page. I manually have to enter field(s) (e.g. nameme, pointme, soundme) inputs in to achieve the purpose, but want to trim things down by taking the POINTME value (e.g. 0-100), and based on that value adding a letter (e.g. R 36-60, K 16-35, M 1-15 or W 0) to the input field (SOUNDME) that will pass along to the database.

I'm not too savvy at this, and have only achieved at how to make the values populate based on POINTME numbers. If anyone can help me, that would be AWESOME!! Thanks.

```
HTML:
<div class="row">
<!-- contestant 1 -->
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" name="nameme" value="No Value">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" name="pointme" id ="v0" onkeyup="calculate()" class="adj" maxlength="2"     value="0">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input type="text" name="soundme" class="adj" maxlength="1" value="0">
</div>
</div>


<input type="text" id="myTextField" onblur="change()"/>

<p id="HighPoints" style="display:none;" >R</p>
<p id="MediumPoints" style="display:none;" >K</p>
<p id="LowPoints" style="display:none;" >M</p>
<p id="NoPoints" style="display:none;" >W</p>





jQuery/Javascript:

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#myTextField").mouseleave(function () {
        var myTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
        var button = document.getElementById('byBtn');

    if (parseFloat(myTextbox) == 0) { // W
        $('#NoPoints').css("display", "block");
        $('#LowPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#HighPoints').css("display", "none");    
    } else if (parseFloat(myTextbox) >= 1 && parseFloat(myTextbox) <= 15) { // M
        $('#NoPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#LowPoints').css("display", "block");
        $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#HighPoints').css("display", "none");
    } else if (parseFloat(myTextbox) >= 16 && parseFloat(myTextbox) <= 35) { // K
        $('#NoPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#LowPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "block");
        $('#HighPoints').css("display", "none");
    } else if (parseFloat(myTextbox) >= 36 && parseFloat(myTextbox) <= 60) { // R
        $('#NoPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#LowPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#HighPoints').css("display", "block");
    } else if (parseFloat(myTextbox) >= 61) { // Error
        alert("Value Points Exceeds Level");
    } else { // NO INPUT
        $('#NoPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#LowPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "none");
        $('#HighPoints').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `$('#somefield').val('R')` …?

Comment: Where would I add that in the code, and can you please show an example of a working condition? Thank you.

Comment: Just add it to the other stuff you are already doing in each of these blocks …?

Comment: So, like so:  JS  $(document).ready(function () {

        if (parseFloat(myTextbox) == 0) { // R
            $('#NoPoints').css("display", "block");
     $('#LowPoints').css("display", "none");
            $('#MediumPoints').css("display", "none");
     $('#HighPoints').css("display", "none");
     $('#somefield').val('R')
        }.....

Comment: And how would I pull that into the actual input field (aside from an echo) if each field would get an answer (letter) based on the previous total??  Here is the actual page of what I am trying to accomplish.   https://wbtfoundation.org/BibleFeud/FastMoney/quantum-leap.php

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. What is “the actual field” referring to?

Comment: actual field is where the corresponding 'letter' goes into...the input field on the web page url I included .... the order is player answer, then point total which then should (hope) automatically puts the letter (eg R, K, M or W) in that field box. Hope that makes better sense. So based on the total point it will put the right letter in the box

Comment: Then you need to go and learn how to _traverse the DOM_ a bit. jQuery has methods to find elements based on their relation to each other, whether they are parents, ancestors, siblings, etc. So you will have to navigate from the field that triggered the event, to the corresponding field that the result should go into. (Like, go up to the parent element `.row` first, then find the soundme field in that.)